# Suddenly TPS is too high like 90K to 3000K but active session is 250

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-13

My DB application connected with pgBouncer and pgpool

Node info:

- 3 Pgbouncer
- 3 pgpool
- 3 dbnode (1 is primary 2 is standby)

`For pgbouncer:  default_pool_size=200 ,reserve_pool_size=10`

`For pgpool: num_init_children=2000 ,max_pool=4`

`For postgres: max_connection=29000, wal_sync_method=fsync, shared_buffer=8GB, wal_buffers=16MB,max_wal_size=8GB,min_wal_size=2GB,max_parallel_workers = 16`

`System: RAM: 40GB, CPU:24, SWAP:16GB`

My issue is that when TPS is too high in that time suddenly my application become slow. Here my average TPS between 40K - 60K. But suddenly it is over 100K-300K where active session 200-290. I am not sure why it is happening? Is it due to slow query or configuration (pgbouncer,pgpool) issue?
Need expert opinion.

Comment: Where are the transactions coming from if not from the app?  If the app is slow, how it sending such a large number of TPS?

Comment: I just login to my PgAdmin with those information>  ip:192.168.43.20, port:9999,          
 db: postgres, user: user_myapp